# Is there a term|phrase for a grading assessment that counts the best m of n?

Tags: grading

I'm assigning weights to different course assessments.

```
Assessment                    Weight
============================  ======
Assignments (best 5 of 8)       50%
Mid-term exam                   20%
Final exam                      30%
```

Is there a word or phrase for a grading scheme that counts the best m of n marks? Example: There are weekly assignments worth 10% each, the best 5 of 8 will be counted.

Comment: "Best 5 of 8" seems like a perfectly good way to describe this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I often see this expressed as "lowest x grades dropped," where x is n minus m.

Comment: For example, in the Blackboard LMS interface, the phrase shown is "Drop [x] lowest grades".

Answer (score 4):

Only half serious, but you could try this:

> The last 5 [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) of the 8 assignments have a weight of 10% each.